# Menu Generation and Dynamic Routes Java/Scala Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to create menus based on sub-folders in Scala Views using Play Framework.

### Question:

How can I feed in variables for the scala templates to use such as User, Menu, and Other and make it work?  The current setup isn't working. And how do I generate a menu that dynamically grabs the child of the current view based on the directory structure?

### Routes Specific File

```
# Test
GET    /admin/:page        controllers.test.TestController.index(page)

GET    /components/:page   controllers.test.TestController.index(page)
```

### Controller

Example of how I'm thinking it will work in the end:

```
   public class TestController extends Controller {
        public Result index(String page) {
            switch (page) {
                case "test1" :
                    List<Role> allRoles = Role.find.all();
                    User user = getCurrentUser();
                    Menu menu = Menu.test();
                    return ok(test1.render(allRoles, user, menu));
                case "test2" :
                    return ok(test2.render());
                default :
                    return notFound();
            }
        }
    }
```

### Views Directory:

```
Views (Folder) 
 |    
 +-- Tools (Folder)
 |  |  
 |  +-- Admin (Folder)
 |  |  |  
 |  |  +-- roles.scala.html 
 |  |  +-- users.scala.html
 |  |  +-- addUsers.scala.html
 |  |  
 |  +--  Components (Folder)
 |  |  |  
 |  |  +-- roles.scala.html 
 |  |  +-- users.scala.html
 |  |  +-- addUsers.scala.html
 |  |  
 |  +-- someFile.scala.html 
 |  +-- someFile2.scala.html
 |    
 +-- main.scala.html
```

### Main Scala File

```
@(title: String, scripts: Html = Html(""))(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SP81D</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!--  Load site-specific customizations after bootstrap. -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/production/ie.min.js")"></script>
            <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="wrapper fixed-header" role="banner">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Site Title  -->
            <div class="site-title col-xs-3">
                LOGO HERE
            </div>

            <!-- Site Navigation -->
            <div class="top-components">
                SEARCH
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    @content

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/production/production.js")"></script>
    @scripts

    </body>
</html>
```

### Sample Admin File:

```
@(roles: List[Role])
@(user: User, menu: Menu)
@import helper._

@Main("identification", scripts) {
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="roles_table" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Role</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              @for(index <- 0 until roles.size) {

                <tr>
                  <td>@roles(index).getName()</td>
                </tr>

              }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 }

@scripts = {
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#roles_table').dynatable();
      });
    </script>
}
```

This sample file doesn't currently work because I need a way to enter some implicit data into all templates and it isn't working well.

## Errors:

#### Fixed by adding the users classes in a better way, missing references before:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getCurrentUser()
  location: class controllers.test.TestController
```

#### FIXED BY ADDING @scripts instead of scripts

```
not found: value scripts
@Main("identification", scripts) { 
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="roles_table" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
```

## Update:

All errors are now fixed, but I can't think of how to dynamically generate the a menu based on the set of files in a view directory and potentially by permissions.

The only thought that comes to mind it to generate a table that has URL's, link names, permission settings, and a parent link and generate the menu from that table.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I'll run it again so that I can get an error and post it in the posts.

Comment: @Kris Added the comment right now it says that scripts isn't a value and it is given clearly in the main template.